# Keycloak Action Token not working if user is disabled

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, keycloak

I have created a custom ActionTokenHandler for reporting fraud user registration.

1. Create an action token link.
2. The user's
   first-time clicks on the link then the handler is getting called and
   **disables** the user - a correct requirement
3. However, when the user clicks again on the same link it does not call my custom
   action token handler and returns **Invalid Username and Password**
   as an error

so my question is are there any way to call the handler even if user is disabled or can we intercept the request before it going to the handler?

[Sorry I can not share my code since it is confendential]

.